# NewsFeed filtering ( Most Recent / Top Stories ) using the legacy rest apis.

Tags: facebook, filtering, facebook-rest-api

Is there a way to filter the news feed to just get the "Most Recent / Top " stories
using REST. I think I can just use the stat/end times to get the most recent. What would be the best way to get the 'Top' stories using REST ( I know this is legacy api's but we already have a system using these and was wondering if its possible to just get the top stories of the news feed using REST ).

From the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.get/ , it doesn't seem to mention anything about Top stories. Was wondering if there is any other way.

Thanks

--sachi